# Why is Safari rendering inline blocks inconsistently when word spacing applied?

Tags: html, css, safari

I am trying to create paragraphs of text where each word is actually a div containing text and a canvas above it (long story!). This means I end up with a series of divs in each paragraph, which I style as inline blocks. These divs look too close together, so I use the CSS word-spacing property to increase the spacing between them.

This works fine on every browser except Safari. On Safari (OS X and iOS), the words spill over the edge of the containing div, even when I fix the width of the container. I suspect that this is a bug in Safari, since all other browsers seem to render my HTML the same way, but does anyone have a way around it?

I have distilled the problem down to this example HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #box1 {
                width: 300px;
                background: Red;
                word-spacing: 50px;
            }

            #box1>div {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            #box2 {
                width: 300px;
                background: Green;
                word-spacing: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box1">
            <div>This</div> <div>text</div> <div>should</div> <div>look</div <div>the</div> <div>same</div> <div>in</div> <div>both</div> <div>boxes</div> <div>but</div> <div>it</div> <div>doesn't</div> <div>in</div> <div>Safari</div>
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
            This text should look the same in both boxes but it doesn't in Safari
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This can also be viewed as a JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4eh6G/

P.S. On older versions of Safari, there seems to be a different problem, where word-spacing appears to have no effect at all in this example. Any fix for this would obviously be great, too!

Comment: It does feel like a bug, true, but why don't you make the divs `inline`? Inline divs (or any elements that are inline by default) would behave the same as undecorated words.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems to have the same result on Safari :(

Comment: That's odd, because I tried using inline instead of inline-block with Safari and it worked as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/4eh6G/3/ However, I must admit I don't have OSX or iOS here and the only Safari I can test is v5.1.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I only tested it on a new version - thanks! It looks like v5 doesn't like to add word-spacing to inline-blocks (but can be fixed by making them simply inline instead), v6 seems to work fine, and v7 has the bizarre problem where the divs spill over their bounding box. I'm on Windows 8 but using BrowserStack to test the different browsers.